# .find doesn't work in jquery 1.4.2 and I can't figure out how to support it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to write my code backwards to support jQuery 1.4.2.  So I am perplexed trying to support older library files.

```
    var n = this;
    e(document).ready(function () {
        var r = e("body").find(n);
        r.attr("placeholder", t);
        r.val(t);
        n.focus(function () {
            e(this).val("")
        }).blur(function () {
            var r = e(n);
            if (r.val() == "") r.val(t)
        })
    })
```

Comment: console.log(n), what does it print out ?

Comment: What is the reason that you are unable to upgrade? 1.4 is pretty old now.

Comment: if you already have `this`, why are you trying to find it in body? you already have it. `var r = e(n)`

Comment: Wait... Have you renamed jQuery as 'e'?

Comment: Thanks for all your help I think I'm going to go with the old school js method of finding a class as .find() isn't working. I did like the idea of extending .find() so the plugin works, but at the moment I don't know how to do that as the jQuery library is a huge file and I don't know where I would steal .find()

Comment: Essentially this is what I'm trying to do.. via a plugin, maybe you guys can debug this jsbin example http://jsbin.com/INonAYo/6/edit please notice that changing the library to 1.6.0 allows the function to do what I want.

Comment: @Blynn you shouldn't use document.ready inside of a plugin. http://jsbin.com/INonAYo/7/edit you don't need to use .find at all.

Comment: Honestly, update your jQuery.

Comment: I don't have the option as the client is using 1.4.2 but thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating your code. First, you don't need to use `$(document).ready()` inside of a plugin, you can let the developer using the plugin take care of that. Next, inside of a plugin, `this` is a jQuery object containing the selected elements. You should iterate over them then act on each one individually.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.labelfixer = function (t) {
        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.attr("placeholder",t);
            this.value = t;
            $this.focus(function(){
                if (this.value == t) {
                    this.value = "";
                }
            });
            $this.blur(function(){
                if (this.value == "") {
                    this.value = t;
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin for helping me out.

Comment: I would have named the plugin "placeholder" since that's the functionality it's recreating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be correct.  The [.find() function](http://api.jquery.com/find/) was added in 1.6.  You could upgrade jQuery or use the .find() using the CSS selector.

If you have the elements with unique .id elements, you could just change your .find function to call that:

```
.find('#' + n.id)
```

Another option, since you have 'this', is that you could just use the basic $(this):

```
var r = $(this);
```

Or, for your code r = e(this);

Comment: Note that it's technically there, it just only supports the css selectors until version 1.6

Comment: My problem is how can I rewrite my code to use .next() or just regular javascript to find the class.

Comment: @Blynn Aah, gotcha.  I see the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but you could check if the find function exists, and then add it to the jquery object if it does not.

Something like

```
if (!$.find) {
    $.fn.find = function () {
        // find function definition
    };
}
```

edit: a better conditional:

```
var version = $.fn.jquery.split('.');
if (version[0] < 2 && version[1] <= 6 && version[2] < 4)
```

last edit: since jsfiddle doesn't have less than 1.6.4 jquery, i can't test this to verify, but I pulled the find function from google's cdn jquery 1.6.4, so the complete monkeypatch would be:

```
var version = $.fn.jquery.split('.');
if (version[0] < 2 && version[1] <= 6 && version[2] < 4) {
$.find = function( expr, context, isXML ) {
var set;

if ( !expr ) {
    return [];
}

for ( var i = 0, l = Expr.order.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    var match,
        type = Expr.order[i];

    if ( (match = Expr.leftMatch[ type ].exec( expr )) ) {
        var left = match[1];
        match.splice( 1, 1 );

        if ( left.substr( left.length - 1 ) !== "\\" ) {
            match[1] = (match[1] || "").replace( rBackslash, "" );
            set = Expr.find[ type ]( match, context, isXML );

            if ( set != null ) {
                expr = expr.replace( Expr.match[ type ], "" );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if ( !set ) {
    set = typeof context.getElementsByTagName !== "undefined" ?
        context.getElementsByTagName( "*" ) :
        [];
}

return { set: set, expr: expr };
```

};

Comment: In 1.4.2, the function exists, it just doesn't support finding by object reference.  Although, he could just rip out the 1.6 version of .find() and monkey-patch it!  :)

Comment: @Richard - if he's going to go as far as doing that, he may as well just upgrade to 1.6 (or beyond anyway).

Comment: @Spudley I'm sure if he had the option of upgrading, he wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: note that `$.find` is not the same as `$.fn.find`, so you might update your if test

Comment: I don't have the option to upgrade at the moment, so a Monkey Patch solution would be best.

Comment: @NeilS: well, I've asked the "why can't you upgrade?" question above, but 1.4 -> 1.6 is really not a big jump in terms of backward compatibility.

Comment: @Spudley Sure, but you're assuming he has the ability to upgrade. He might be interfacing with legacy code that cannot be overwritten, or dealing with a third party site/ codebase that doesn't allow him to make a change.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of this ? I have just binned out one example using `1.4.2` for `find` and it's working properly .

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body id='bd'>
 <ul class="level-1">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li class="item-ii">II
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
        <ul class="level-3">
          <li class="item-1">1</li>
          <li class="item-2">2</li>
          <li class="item-3">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$('li.item-ii').find('li').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Find the bin here :http://jsbin.com/INonAYo/1/edit

Comment: The [.find function](http://api.jquery.com/find/) works fine, but it doesn't support the object reference lookup.

Comment: @Blynn : You have coded it wrong, in the class name you did not give the `.`. Look at this : http://jsbin.com/INonAYo/4/edit .The CSS selector works just fine.

Comment: I realized that, but still can't figure out why .find() isn't working for my function.

Comment: @Blynn : Can you post a sample HTML mark up and let us know what you hope to `find` from there. It will  then become easier to figure this out.

Comment: @Blynn I may be wrong, but it looks like you're passing the JS object `this` into the jquery `find`. I think you'd need to pass in the jQuery object `$(this)` for it to work.

Comment: @Blynn : You can inspect the label in the text box and you will see, the label is applied, it's just not visible.

Comment: I've solved my problem check out the answer here: jsbin.com/INonAYo/7/edit